ModuleNotFound Error in unstructured.document.html
I was executing this code
from unstructured.documents.html import HTMLDocument

And I am getting an error which is
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 from unstructured.documents.html import HTMLDocument
      3 # Load your HTML file
      4 html_file_path = 'UBER_2019.html'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unstructured.documents.html'

So what Can I do to resolve this?

You need to install unstructured module.
pip install unstructured

https://pypi.org/project/unstructured/
restart your kernel after installation and then try:
import unstructured
from unstructured.documents.html import HTMLDocument


I have already installed the module.

@PiyushJoshi please see the edit.
